# Can VBSCRIPT run on every version of Windows?

Tags: windows, vbscript

Are there any dependencies for running vbscript on windows?
Can vbscript run on all windows versions?
For the Windows versions that vbscript can not run on, what are the necessary dependencies that i must download for vbs to run on that windows version?

Answer (score 2):

Talking about [Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84).aspx), not about [Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x7h1hfk.aspx) nor [Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx):

1. [VBScript will be going away at some point. When? I do not know.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/04/16/hey-scripting-guy-april-16-2010.aspx)

> ... We have not deprecated VBScript; it is simply in maintenance mode.
>   Maintenance mode is probably one step before it becomes deprecated.
>   The final step, of course, is that it becomes obsolete, which means
>   that it is no longer supported. Because VBScript is part of the
>   operating system, it will follow the same life cycle as the operating
>   system with which it ships. Therefore, VBScript will at least be
>   supported as long as Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 are. If it
>   ships in Windows 8, it will be supported as long as that operating
>   system.
>  In the meantime, you should begin learning Windows
>   PowerShell because Windows PowerShell is the future of administrative
>   scripting...

VBScript runs in Windows 8 (I have no knowledge on Windows 10, sorry).

2. [VBScript is no longer supported in IE11 edge mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx)

> As of Internet Explorer 11, VBScript is considered deprecated and
>   should no longer be used as a scripting language for IE11. Webpages
>   displayed in IE11 mode won't execute VBScript code...

Comment: VBS files runs on Windows 10 as well.

Comment: @PankajJaju the question is, for how long? :(

Comment: @Tomamais According to the quote `it will follow the same life cycle as the operating system with which it ships` which means, by Microsoft standards, that the planned obsolescence is 10 years after publication of Windows 10. But also since Microsoft declared Win10 to be "the last Windows ever", it might be supported for much longer. At the very least, one should expect to be supported for the full life time of Windows 10.

Comment: Of course, "supported" means **absolute nothing** to the end user, as long as the interpreter ships with the OS or one is able to install it. The scripts developed with it are very likely to continue running flawlessly for years afterward, like many other "deprecated" systems that still run today.