# Is there a way to fix the size of the string

Tags: vbscript

Is there a way I can fix the number of characters of the string.

```
Sub check ()
    logfilepath = "D:\surendra\VBScript\File_Compare\log.txt"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set logFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(logfilepath, true)
    myarray = Array(1,2.0,5.83,100)
    For Each element In myarray
    logFile.WriteLine "       " & element & "       " & 0 
    Next
   logFile.Close
End Sub
```

out come of the above code is

```
   1       0
   2       0
   5.83       0
   100       0
```

But I want to print in the way as

```
   1       0
   2       0
5.83       0
 100       0
```

based on the number of characters spaces should be adjusted to get total of 8 character length.

any command to fix the character length of the string  like Format command in TCL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line --> `logFile.WriteLine "       " & element & "       " & 0`

To ---> `logFile.WriteLine element & String(8-Len(element)," ") & 0`

I've used [String](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_string.asp) function to add spaces based on the length of each element.

Answer (score 0):

On your WriteLine use Format @x8 for right aligning & Left to 8th char to clip your string i.e.

```
logFile.WriteLine "      |" & Format(Left(element,8), "@@@@@@@@") & "|      " & 0
```

References:

[String Manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/string-manipulation-summary)

[Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Answer (score 0):

```
logFile.WriteLine "       " & element & "       " & 0
```

to

```
logFile.WriteLine Right( Space(8) & CStr( element),8) & "       " & 0
```

Check [Functions (VBScript) reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/3ca8tfek%28v%3Dvs.84%29) for `Right`, `Space` and `CStr` functions detailed description. You might be interested in [`FormatNumber` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ws343esk%28v%3Dvs.84%29) as well.

However, instead VBScript, [you should begin learning Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32507398/3439404) because Windows PowerShell is the future of administrative scripting (at least for Microsoft Windows operating systems).